# Using assign inside a for loop

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to assign I/O vectors inside a for loop in order to save space. I am unsure if this is not possible or I am running into a syntax issue.

I have tried using generate and am still running into issues

My current code is as follows:

```
module Test_IO
(
     output [7:0] led,  
     input  [7:0] sw 
);

genvar i;
generate
for(i = 0;i < 8; i = i + 1)
{
     assign led<i> = sw<i>;
}
endgenerate

endmodule
```

I was hoping to save space instead of having to use 8 assign statements but I have been receiving the following error:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - 
"C:/Users/Danie/Desktop/Digilent/Projects/Test_IO/Test_IO.v" Line 31: 
Syntax error near "{".
```

Comment: what language are you writing it in? it is not verilog.

Comment: How is it going to save the space ? For loop in this case is pointless... just simple assignment will do the job.

Comment: Please _read a manual_. You don't have a clear grasp of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using verilog. Try the below code. You really don't need a genvar for the assignment you are doing.

```
module Test_IO
 (
 output [7:0] led,  
 input  [7:0] sw 
 );

 genvar i;
 generate
 for(i = 0;i < 8; i = i + 1)
    assign led[i] = sw[i];
 endgenerate

 endmodule
```

Alternatively you may try the below one too

```
module Test_IO
 (
 output reg [7:0] led,  
 input  [7:0] sw 
 );

 integer i;

 always@(*)
 begin
   for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
     led[i] = sw[i];
 end

 endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is syntax. In verilog use **begin** and **end**, not **{** and **}**

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i = 0;i < 8; i = i + 1)
{
     assign led<i> = sw<i>;
}
endgenerate
```

becomes

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i = 0;i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
    assign led[i] = sw[i];
end
endgenerate
```

sometimes compilers requires the generate loop to be named using  **: NAME** after begin

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i = 0;i < 8; i = i + 1) begin : ASSIGN_GEN
    assign led[i] = sw[i];
end
endgenerate
```